# Saving the foreign key in a hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two tables 1. User 2. USersLocation, In the location table I use the userId as foreign key. When I save the location object in database I want to save the current user Id as well in the table.

What I have tried so far is

SocialLogin Controller

```
 SocialAuthManager manager = socialAuthTemplate.getSocialAuthManager();
 AuthProvider provider = manager.getCurrentAuthProvider();
 Profile userProfile = provider.getUserProfile();
```

Location Controller

```
  UsersLocation location = new UsersLocation();
  location.setSourceLat(SOURCE_LATITUDE);
  location.setSourceLng(SOURCE_LONGITUDE);
  location.setDestinationLat(DEST_LATITUDE);
  location.setDestinationLng(DEST_LONGITUDE);
  location.setUserId((User) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, "userId"));
  placesService.saveLocaion(location);
```

The Userslocation class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
public class UsersLocation implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private double sourceLat;
private double sourceLng;
private double destinationLat;
private double destinationLng;

public UsersLocation(){}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int locationId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;

public void setUserId(User user){
    this.user = user;
}

public User getUserId(){
    return user;
}

@Column(name = "SourceLat", nullable = false)
public double getSourceLat(){
    return sourceLat;
}

public void setSourceLat(double sourceLat){
    this.sourceLat = sourceLat;
}

@Column(name = "SourceLng", nullable = false)
public double getSourceLng(){
    return sourceLng;
}

public void setSourceLng(double sourceLng){
    this.sourceLng = sourceLng;
}

@Column(name = "DestinationLat", nullable = false)
public double getDestinationLat(){
    return destinationLat;
}

public void setDestinationLat(double destinationLat){
    this.destinationLat = destinationLat;
}

@Column(name = "DestinationLng", nullable = false)
public double getDestinationLng(){
    return destinationLng;
}

public void setDestinationLng(double destinationLng){
    this.destinationLng = destinationLng;
}

}
```

User Class

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "users")
 public class User implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer userId;
private String email;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;   
private String location;

public User() {

}

@Id
@Column(name = "userId", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

public Integer setUserId(Integer socialId) {
    return this.userId = socialId;
}

@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}


public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Column(name = "firstName", nullable = true, length = 20)
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}


public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "lastName", nullable = true, length = 20)
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}


public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name = "location", nullable = true, length = 50)
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}


public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

}
```

When I save the location I get the userId NULL,I am new to hibernate kindly help me

Thanks

Comment: Could you show also database schema and mapping of User class?

Comment: Also post the actual error logs

Comment: There is no error it save the location object but the userId in the locations table is null

Comment: create table users (
        userId integer not null,
        email varchar(50) not null,
        firstName varchar(20),
        lastName varchar(20),
        location varchar(50),
        primary key (userId)
    )

Comment: Ok check if this line of code returns a valid User object with all user values as expected. (User) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, "userId")

Comment: how I set this value is : 
Integer userId = Integer.parseInt(provider.getUserProfile().getValidatedId());
WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "userId", userId);

Comment: That's wrong. It needs the full User object later for location.setUserId(). So set the full User object in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the whole user object to the session like below instead of just the userId, as later you need to set the full User object in location.setUserId(user);

```
WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "userId", user)
```

Comment: and then when I get it from session location.setUser((User) WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, "user")); 

it gives me ClassCast Exception org.brickred.socialauth.Profile cannot be cast to de.tum.in.aics.thesis.project.models.User

Comment: Are you saving the same User class in the session. It needs to be the same class or in the same valid inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Its not the same class , I am using socialauth for facebook login

Comment: In UsersLocation.java you have defined "public void setUserId(User user)" then it would expect a User not a org.brickred.socialauth.Profile. How does your User.java class looks like ? May be you have to populate you User object from the Profile. It's your design I only have to assume without seeing your code.

Comment: Yes I populate my User from Profile, let me put more code

Comment: Then after populating the User from the Profile, use this User not the Profile, hence the ClassCastException.

Comment: Thanks Jay for the help once I populate the User from Profile and save it in session it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you want to save a `Location` in the database along with the `UserId`, you have this relation wrong. This should be a `OneToOne`, since each location will have only one `UserId` associated.

On the other hand, if you're trying to set a location capable of storing many `userId`s, you're also doing it wrong because you should be saving a set of users, something like:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "UsersLocation")
private Set<User> user;
```

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but I'm pretty sure your mistake lies in the fact that you're doing the relations in the wrong way.

Comment: but one location can have different users but at one time it can have only one user